# How do I disable the triple vibrate of Viber?

Tags: notifications, vibration, viber-messenger, moto-x

When I get a notification in Viber it vibrates three times, as well as playing the sound. How do I stop it from vibrating three times!?

I saw the question about receiving multiple notifications but that doesn't apply as I don't use Viber for SMS.

Answer (score 1):

In version 5.3.0 for Android, on my HTC one m8 I couldn't find ANY option to disable vibrations, exept for the "incoming Call" one. 
So my phone sounds one time and vibrates 3 times when I receive a message...

Later edit: Just wrote Viber, they answered that a fix will be available shortly !

Answer (score 0):

Go to :Settings =>
Notifications =>
At the bottom you will see  Options for Notification sound and Vibrate when ringing option  (just un check them and done.)

Answer (score 0):

Use **System Sounds** instead of Viber Default Sound, Vibration for **Messages** Depends on it!